# Will my paper be published?

Tags: conference

I submitted my abstract at MISG-2015 conference at Malaysia. I got a mail stating that it was accepted. Does this mean that my abstract will be published?

Comment: Do you have your full content paper ready?

Comment: yes it is ready

Comment: http://www.globalilluminators.org just does not seem right. Are you 100% sure that this is a legit conference?

Comment: The [main areas of inquiry](http://www.globalilluminators.org/misg-2015-kualalumpur-malaysia/conference-scope-sub-themes/) at MISG-2015 include agriculture, complex analysis, set theory, nanotechnology, climatology, cardiology, HIV/AIDS, biotechnology, robotics, aeronautical engineering, anthropology, religious studies, small business management, water desalination technologies, etc. (together with an unbelievably long list of other topics), while the [scientific review committee](http://www.globalilluminators.org/misg-2015-kualalumpur-malaysia/scientific-review-committee/) has 12 members.

Comment: Even taking into account the [six-person advisory board](http://www.globalilluminators.org/misg-2015-kualalumpur-malaysia/advisory-board/) as well as the committee, I can't believe the conference could do a responsible job of handling all the topics they solicit papers on.  It's just way too many topics, with far too few people to have genuine expertise in everything listed.

Comment: Ask the magic 8 ball!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your answer
http://www.globalilluminators.org/misg-2015-kualalumpur-malaysia/publication-prospect/
Your abstract and paper if you submit will be published in the proceedings, they are then put into selection for journals, but there is zero guarantee about that.

Comment: +1 I think the question was mainly about the conference proceedings, but it's good to include both!