# Is it valuable to present a paper at an international conference?

Tags: conference, undergraduate

My abstract/paper has been selected at 2nd International MISG-2015 conference held at Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia. I would like to know if it's valuable for an Undergraduate student to present paper at this conference and will it have a high impact when I apply for an university for Masters?

Comment: Welcome to Academia! Interesting question - you may also be interested in this question: [Attending conferences as a first-year undergrad](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16689/4140)

Comment: Could you please edit your question to clarify how your paper "has been selected"? Did you submit it, was it peer-reviewed (abstract only/full text), and was it accepted based on that review? Or were you e-mailed by the conference organizers with an invitation to present your paper (or your research in general) on that conference?

Comment: If that's the same conference discussed in the comments [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/43231/will-my-paper-be-published), then I don't think it will have a positive impact when applying for a master's degree.  But I have no direct familiarity with the conference.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper yes, it was peer reviewed. And they sent me an acceptance letter.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician It's the same one.

Answer (score 8):

I've got a fairly pessimistic view of the value of publishing in obscure, questionable places.  As an admissions committee member, I periodically see applicants with papers in journals or conferences I've never heard of.  Without more information, publishing in an unknown venue is completely meaningless, since the world is full of junk venues that will publish literally anything.  Many of them claim to do peer review and enforce scholarly standards, but they will actually [accept nonsense text](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/scigen/).  Unfortunately, there are no magic words (like "peer review" or "international") that will certify a publishing venue, because some venues simply lie, while others are honest but incompetent.

When I run across a completely unfamiliar venue listed in a graduate school application, I do some quick web searches to try to find out more about it.  Sometime I discover that I should have known about it, or that it's a perfectly reasonable and respectable venue that just doesn't have much of an international reputation, but often it looks pretty suspicious to me.  In those cases, I have one of two reactions, depending on how the application comes across.  Either I think "Oh no, this applicant was tricked into publishing a possibly worthwhile paper in a worthless journal", or I think "Hey, this applicant is publishing in a worthless journal to try to manipulate the system".  The former is more likely, with the latter being mainly when the application contains unseemly self-promotion or exaggerations.  Being tricked is mildly negative, since it suggests the applicant was naive and insufficiently careful, but it's not such a terrible thing.  (The main outcome would be that the paper counts for little or nothing.)  Being manipulative is very bad.

If you can't evaluate a conference yourself, it's important to seek advice from people who can, since sending good work to a bad venue is not a winning strategy.  As for MISG-2015, I can't speak from any direct knowledge, but the [list of topics](http://www.globalilluminators.org/misg-2015-kualalumpur-malaysia/conference-scope-sub-themes/) strikes me as absurdly broad, and I find it difficult to believe any [scientific committee](http://www.globalilluminators.org/misg-2015-kualalumpur-malaysia/scientific-review-committee/) of twelve people could possibly do a responsible job of handling submissions from such diverse areas.

Comment: Another red flag: I downloaded the [proceedings for last year's MISG conference](http://www.globalilluminators.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/MISG-14-Proceeding.pdf). The conference lasted one day (08:30-18:00) and included a grand total of 26 presentations (the three conference "tracks" were consecutive rather than concurrent, and the website shows another four tracks which presumably received no submissions at all). When the number of conference *topics* exceeds the number of *presentations* by an order of magnitude, it doesn't give a very good impression.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can see discussion about this conference [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/43231/will-my-paper-be-published) that suggests the conference does not have enough staff to excel in its claimed fields of expertise or review the submitted papers properly. A publication will, at first glance, look good on an application, but any investigation by the admissions board will highlight the fact that this conference is not prestigious and probably a scam. I believe that it would be possible for this to have a negative impact on your applications. The only potential redeeming factor would be if the process of its submission to this conference provides an opportunity to publish elsewhere. This seems unlikely given the conference but a real publication elsewhere would have a much greater positive impact on your research career.
I recommend talking to academics at your university about this conference and if they have any knowledge of it.

Comment: "I believe that it would be impossible for this to have a negative impact on your applications". I disagree. This particular conference, as discussed here and in the linked thread, is *obviously* an academic scam. If you get taken in by a *good* scam, nobody will hold that against you. But if you fall for such an *obvious* scam and then even include the paper on your CV, that *will* reflect badly on your power of discernment. (Or did you want to write "possible" instead of "impossible"? Your answer almost reads that way.)

Comment: Yeah its interesting, I think I trust people too much, I don't feel like I have enough evidence to know this is a scam, but maybe others, yourself included, feel that what has been discussed is conclusive?

Comment: I personally *strongly* feel that there is *no possibility whatsoever* that [this](http://www.globalilluminators.org/misg-2015-kualalumpur-malaysia/conference-scope-sub-themes/) could *not* be a scam.

Comment: Agreed actually, I looked at all this before (as mentioned) but I somehow forgot how vast their subject list was.